# WPF Boing demo needs life support

Tags: wpf, xaml, amiga

Remember the Amiga boing demo?  I was reading a 25th anniversary of the Amiga article and they mentioned it.  Brought back some memories.  I remember a WPF (called Avalon at the time) demo put together to mimic it.  I did some googling and found it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424020846/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danlehen/archive/2004/11/23/268252.aspx).  However, it seems to be extremely out-of-date as the XAML markup and the code-behind is rife with errors when I attempt to build in VS 2010 (re-targeted to CLR 4.0 Client Profile).  Are there any WPF gurus out there who are able and willing to bring it into this decade?  This would go a long way to understanding the WPF/XAML stack for me.  Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm using the slightly updated version I just found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419163309/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danlehen/archive/2005/01/04/346731.aspx).

**Edit the 2nd:** I've gotten it to compile and show the nice gradient blue background, but not the bouncing checkered ball.  The problem is that I cannot find the modern equivalent of:

```
        <x:Include x:Content="{ball}" />
```

Comment: OMG as if SO wasn't distracting enough you now go and do this - shakes fist at sky... :) I am so not a WPF guru but I guess I'm just about to learn some more :).

Comment: You may also be interested on this one. http://10rem.net/lab/commodore-64-emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recreated this stuff for .NET 4.0. Solution is available by [Boing link](http://www.mediafire.com/?889d88ayz8j53n1). Thanks for your suggestion. It was interesting!

**Added**

I have added solution code to [codepaste.net](http://codepaste.net). You can view it [here](http://codepaste.net/hrjzmb).

Comment: +1 I didn't even know things could be made of awesome before today... :P ♡

Comment: I know it's pretty old question - but the link to codepaste is not working anymore - can you put it back up if you still have it 4 years now after the question :)

Comment: The source code is still available by link to mediafire: http://www.mediafire.com/?889d88ayz8j53n1